# NodeJS HTTPS Error (520)

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I've no idea what this error, or how to fix it.  Still learning NodeJS, so sorry for noobness.

I am also using Cloudflare.

```
node: ../src/util-inl.h:196: TypeName* node::Unwrap(v8::Local<v8::Object>) 
[with TypeName = node::TLSWrap]: Assertion `(object->InternalFieldCount()) > (0)' 
failed.
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/my.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/my.pem')
}   

var serverPort = 2096;
var app = require('express')();
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(serverPort, function(){
    console.log('Connected on port *:%s', serverPort);
});
```

Then on the client side

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com:2096');
```

As soon as I do something, the console shows this

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:2096/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=cTlTQnHvcv0LwbBdAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 520
```

Comment: Well, even though you're declaring it, I don't see where you're using `serverPort ` in the creation of the server.

Comment: @Andy My bad, updated code.  Forgot to include it =p

Answer (score 1):

The 520 error is essentially a “catch-all” response for when the origin server returns something unexpected or something that is not tolerated/interpreted (protocol violation or empty response).

While the 520 error can be triggered by very unique and strange edge-case scenarios, they are generally caused by:

- Connection resets (following a successful TCP handshake)
- Headers exceed Cloudflare’s header size limit (over 8kb)
- Empty response from origin
- Invalid HTTP response
- HTTP response missing response headers